# Java: Drawing "Random" Stars

Tags: java, loops, random, drawing, polygon

I'm trying to take this code I finally got working for drawing one star and am confused on how to get it working for drawing 25 different stars (such as different sides and spikinness but I am unsure how to go about it exactly. I assume I would make a new random variable `int randomStars = (int)(Math.random()*25+1); // Variable for 25 Random Stars` to randomly generate the stars but I'm kind of confused where to take it from there.

I'd appreciate the help.

My Code (Using [DrawingPanel.java](http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java)):

```
import java.awt.*;

public class StarSampler {

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(500, 500);
           Graphics2D g = panel.getGraphics();
           g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
           panel.setBackground(new Color(250, 0, 0));

           fillStar(g, 250, 250, 150, 5, .3); // How to rotate it to start at center?
       }

       public static void fillStar(Graphics2D g, int ctrX, int ctrY, int radius, int nPoints, double spikiness)
       {
           double xDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];
           double yDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];

           int xPoint[] = new int[2*nPoints]; 
           int yPoint[] = new int[2*nPoints];

           nPoints = (int) (nPoints * 2);

           int randomStars = (int)(Math.random()*25+1); // Variable for 25 Random Stars

          // Would Nestest loop go here? for (randomStars++; randomStars < 25; randomStars++)
           for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
            {
                double iRadius = (i % 2 == 0) ? radius : (radius * spikiness);
                double angle = (270) + (i * 360.0) / (nPoints);

                xPoint[i] = (int) (ctrX + iRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
                yPoint[i] = (int) (ctrY + iRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));
            }
                g.fillPolygon(xPoint, yPoint, nPoints); // Creates polygon
       }
}
```

My Output:

[image: Current Output]

Comment: do you want to paint them next to each other or one after another?

Comment: @Paul The goal was next to each other but I suppose randomly anywhere could work if they weren't entirely on top of each other.

Comment: alright. First of: you need to create two numbers per star (assuming they're equally sized): radius and spikiness. Then use the `fillStar` method, to render the stars. Just loop over the positions where you want to insert the stars  and use them as center-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Build up slowly.  First concentrate on positioning two stars, just two.  Pick the coordinates for the centre of the stars and place them.  Adjust to get it right (your first attempt will probably have errors).  Test, fix, test again, fix again.  Repeat.

Then play with the spikiness and other changes so the stars aren't identical.  When, and only when, that is tested and working move on to three, four etc. stars.  With more stars you will have to be more careful to avoid overlaps.